# Is it appropriate to use "father" in a legal context?

Tags: kinship-terms

In a legal petition, how do you describe, in a formal manner, someone being the father of another person?

Is this example acceptable?

> John Doe, deceased, **father** of the plaintiff.

Comment: Yes. What do you think is wrong with it? it is clear and unambiguous.

Comment: I was not sure, as I am not used to legal language.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but the question's title needs work. That's probably the reason for it.

Comment: What makes you think there is a legal term for 'father'? Do you have a different one in your native language?

Comment: @Mitch - No, but at the time I posted the question, I was doing a translation of a court document which involves inheritance left to a plaintiff from his father, and that prompted me to post the question.  I did check w/ http://thesaurus.com/ as I normally do, but still wasn't sure.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Father* fits the bill; it's the appropriate word to use. It's not informal or anything. It's the proper word for the relation.
Another word you can use is '*parent*', but that brings about a bit of ambiguity concerning whether you're talking about the mother or father.

So I'd say go with 'father'. Here are some more words which mean father:

- dad/daddy
- old man
- sire
- ancestor (to further clarify perhaps you can use *primary ancestor*. On second thoughts that may actually confuse more than clarify)
- pop/papa

;)

Comment: None of these is appropriate for the given context.

Comment: @ColinFine Did you miss the ';)' at the end?

Comment: @Sabuncu Yes, 'father' is better than all the terms mentioned in my answer. It's not informal at all.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who have commented (has commented? - on pins and needles at this site, English-wise!).

Comment: Yes, I did miss the smiley. While some degree of levity is fine, an answer which consists of one third of a line of actual answer and ten lines of emboldened irrelevance is inappropriate, smiley or no smiley.

Comment: @Sabuncu yes, it's 'has commented'. :)

Comment: @ColinFine There, I edited it to make it more serious. :/

Answer (score 2):

For a legal context, yes, **father** is perfect.

In legal documents, "informal" names for a parent, such as *daddy*, *pappa*, *pop*, and *old man* should be avoided. *Dad* can be used, but is still rather informal, and I would still argue against it in a serious document.

Comment: I did upvote your answer. ;-)